# Timer in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I do my first chrome extension and I have a problem already.
There is a `select` in my popup.html
When I choose some `option` my timer starts from 00:00:00
It's works when my popup window is opened, but when I close my popup this function stops working.
But I need the timer to work after I closed my popup. And after open it again, the timer should continue to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script should communicate between popup and background page to save its value.

When you start your counter, popup should pass some message to background page and the real counter should run there (background). Remember that popup can be closed at any time. And when it's opened again, you ask background page if it has a running timer and get its value.

Удачи :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also save the datetime start in the memory (localStorage for example) and reinit your timer when it's open again.

In this case, if the user close Google Chrome, and by the way the background page, you can reinit the timer with the good value and run the timer.